# Targeting parent div

Tags: php, arrays

I have the following php:

```
<?php echo '<div class="button_1" data-post_id="' .$id. '">' ;?>
     <div class="button_2">
        Button
     </div>
</div>
```

Then my js:

```
jQuery(document).on( 'click', '.button_2', function(e) {    
    var post_id = jQuery(this).data("post_id");//??     
}
```

How do I target the `data-post_id` of the `div` with `class="button_1"` for the `var post_id`?

Thanks

Comment: Just some improvement advice - instead of `<?php echo '<div class="button_1" data-post_id="' .$id. '">' ;?>` do `<div class="button_1" data-post_id="<?php echo $id ?>">` will be MUCH better

Comment: Thank you for the advice. Just a quick question. In what regard is it better? thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try with `parents` -

```
jQuery(this).parents('.button_1').data("post_id");
```

Or

```
jQuery(this).closest('.button_1').data("post_id");
```